# XML in a XSLT-Stlesheet tabel

Tags: xslt

I have a problem. I made a table in a xslt stylesheet. Now I don't know how to put only one Unit-node in the upper table and then all the funktion nodes under that. For the second, third... Unit-node I want both tables under that.

example in a picture in my dropbox (I have not enough point on stckoverflow)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/jfzii4ytllfb6m9/Mappe1.pdf?dl=0

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<PLC_LOG>
  <HostName>DERTLP0350</HostName>
  <Unit>
    <Line>123456</Line>
    <Funktion>
      <sName>CounterDown1</sName>
      <sDescription>automatic</sDescription>
      <tMaxExecutionTime>T#3s</tMaxExecutionTime>
      <Timestamp>2014-12-15-14:11:10.298</Timestamp>
      <Line>12345678</Line>
      <bFinish>TRUE</bFinish>
      <bResult>TRUE</bResult>
    </Funktion><sName>CounterDown</sName>
    <sDescription>Test of the CounterDown</sDescription>
    <tMaxExecutionTime>T#15s</tMaxExecutionTime>
    <bFinish>TRUE</bFinish>
    <bResult>FALSE</bResult>
    <Timestamp>2014-12-15-14:11:11.179</Timestamp>
  </Unit>
  <Unit>
    <Line>123456</Line>
    <Funktion>
      <sName>CounterDown1</sName>
      <sDescription>automatic</sDescription>
      <tMaxExecutionTime>T#3s</tMaxExecutionTime>
      <Timestamp>2014-12-15-14:11:10.298</Timestamp>
      <Line>12345678</Line>
      <bFinish>TRUE</bFinish>
      <bResult>FALSE</bResult>
    </Funktion><sName>CounterDown</sName>
    <sDescription>Test of the CounterDown</sDescription>
    <tMaxExecutionTime>T#15s</tMaxExecutionTime>
    <bFinish>TRUE</bFinish>
    <bResult>FALSE</bResult>
  <Timestamp>2014-12-15-14:11:11.179</Timestamp>
  </Unit>
</PLC_LOG>
```

My made my table with this code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:template match = "/">
  <html>
   <head>
    <title>Automated Test of the System</title>
    <style type="text/css">
     h1 {color: #000000}
     h2 {color: #000000}
    </style>
   </head>
   <body bgcolor="white">

    <h1 >
     <a name="Content">Testreport PLC</a>
    </h1>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </body>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="PLC_LOG">

  <table border="1">
   <thead>
    <tr bgcolor="#BDBDBD">
     <th width="650" align="center">HostName</th>
     <th width="650" align="center">Link to Configuration</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <xsl:for-each select="/PLC_LOG">
     <tr>
      <td align="center">
       <xsl:value-of select="HostName"/>
      </td>
      <td align="center">
       <xsl:value-of select="HostName"/>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
   </tbody>
  </table>

 
  <table border="1">
   <thead>
    <tr bgcolor="#0070C0">
     <th colspan="7">TestUNIT</th>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#0070C0">
     <th width="200" align="center">Name</th>
     <th width="325" align="center">Description</th>
     <th width="325" align="center">Message</th>
     <th width="100" align="center">MaxExecutionTime</th>
     <th width="150" align="center">Timestamp</th>
     <th width="100" align="center">TestFinish</th>
     <th width="100" align="center">Result</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <xsl:for-each select="/*/Unit">
     <tr>
      <td>
       <xsl:value-of select="sName"/>
      </td>
      <td>
       <xsl:value-of select="sDescription"/>
      </td>
      <td>
       <xsl:for-each select="node()[starts-with(name(), 'Line')]">
       <xsl:value-of select="."/>
       </xsl:for-each>
      </td>
      <td align="center">
       <xsl:value-of select="tMaxExecutionTime"/>
      </td>
      <td>
       <xsl:value-of select="Timestamp"/>
      </td>
       <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="bFinish='TURE'">
         <td bgcolor="#00FF00" align="center">
          <b>Passed</b>
         </td>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="bFinish='TRUE'">
         <td bgcolor="red" align="center">
          <b>Failed</b>
         </td>
        </xsl:when>
       </xsl:choose>
      <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="bResult='TRUE'">
        <td bgcolor="#00FF00" align="center">
         <b>Passed</b>
        </td>
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:when test="bResult='FALSE'">
        <td bgcolor="red" align="center">
         <b>Failed</b>
        </td>
       </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
     </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
   </tbody>
  </table>
  

        <table border="1">    
         <thead>
    <tr bgcolor="#0099ff">
     <th colspan="7">TestFunktion</th>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#0099ff">
     <th width="200" align="center">Name</th>
     <th width="325" align="center">Description</th>
     <th width="325" align="center">Message</th>
     <th width="100" align="center">MaxExecutionTime</th>
     <th width="150" align="center">Timestamp</th>
     <th width="100" align="center">TestFinish</th>
     <th width="100" align="center">Result</th>    
           </tr>  
         </thead>
    <tbody>
      <xsl:for-each select="/*/*/Funktion">
       <tr>
        <td>
         <xsl:value-of select="sName"/>
        </td>
        <td>
         <xsl:value-of select="sDescription"/>
        </td>
        <td>
         <xsl:for-each select="node()[starts-with(name(), 'Line')]">
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
         </xsl:for-each>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
         <xsl:value-of select="tMaxExecutionTime"/>
        </td>
        <td>
         <xsl:value-of select="Timestamp"/>
        </td>
        <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="bFinish='TRUE'">
          <td bgcolor="#00FF00" align="center">
           <b>Passed</b>
          </td>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:when test="bFinish='FALSE'">
          <td bgcolor="red" align="center">
           <b>Failed</b>
          </td>
         </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="bResult='TRUE'">
          <td bgcolor="#00FF00" align="center">
           <b>Passed</b>
          </td>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:when test="bResult='FALSE'">
          <td bgcolor="red" align="center">
           <b>Failed</b>
          </td>
         </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
       </tr>
     </xsl:for-each>
    </tbody>
          </table> 
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks for help!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very confusing, esp. since the picture does not seem to match the example input. I would suggest you concentrate first on getting the structure right. Try the following as your starting point:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="PLC_LOG/Unit"/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Unit">
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="7">TestUNIT</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Message</th>
                <th>MaxExecutionTime</th>
                <th>Timestamp</th>
                <th>TestFinish</th>
                <th>Result</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="sName"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="sDescription"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="Line"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="tMaxExecutionTime"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="Timestamp"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="bFinish"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="bResult"/></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="7">TestFunktion</th>
            </tr>   
            <tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="Funktion[1]/*">
                    <th><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/></th>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>   
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Funktion"/>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Funktion">
    <tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>   
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Once you have the table structure and contents the way you want them, add CSS styling as necessary.